# how to pass data from an application page class to a ViewModel class WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

In my WP8 application page,i am generating the data for my ViewModel that i am using to plot a chart.The  generated data is passed to the ViewModel as a List.That is where i have a 
bit of a problem because they are different classes and the list's visibility scope doesn't extend to the ViewModel's collection.

This is the data in the application page(sort of an example of what i'm doing):

```
namespace M
{

public partial class SampleRecord : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    List<Record> r_List = new List<Record>();
    public SampleRecord()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      //after proceesing the data
        r_List.Add(1, 100);
        r_List.Add(2, 200);
        r_List.Add(3, 300);
    }
    }
    }
```

The ViewModel class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> Collection { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        GenerateData();
    }
    private void GenerateData()
    {

        for(int i<0; i<r_List.Count; i++){\

         this.Collection.Add(add elements of the list to the collection);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Tried declaring the List in the App.xaml.cs so that it is accessible eveywhere but it isn't recognized in the application page class.

Comment: You created List in View, want fill it in ViewModel and retrieve back to View? Why you don't declare and fill it in one place?(in ViewModel preferable)

Comment: @YuriDorokhov,,created it in View because that's where the datasource is,can't move it to ViewModel becase of the data flow...i want to fill the ViewModel using the list becase the ViewModel contains the data for the chart

Comment: You have bad architecture of your application. You can create public method with List<Record> parameter and it solve your problem. But rewrite your code for separating view and login are better way in your case.

Answer (score 0):

> Having your data source in a view is a huge *no no* if you are using MVVM. If you insist on having it there then you are *not* using MVVM.

However, if you just create a `DependencyProperty` in your view's code behind to hold the data collection, then you can just data bind to it from there. Let's assume your property is called `Collection`...

```
Collection = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
GenerateData();
```

... you could data bind to it from the view like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourLocalPrefix:YourView}}}" ... />
```

However, I can't stress enough how important it is to separate your views from your data access.